# How to make check box in each row selected by default in Vaadin table?

Tags: checkbox, vaadin

How to make the checkbox in each row selected by default in a Vaadin Table?
I have gone through a Vaadin example, which specifies that `field.setValue(true)` will make checkboxes in each row selected.

This solution is not working for me. Here I have used `DefaultFieldFactory` to generate fields for each row.

```
public class ReviewTimesheetTable extends ViewComponent {

private Map<ReviewTimesheetTableDto, HashMap<String, AbstractField<?>>> tableItem = new HashMap<ReviewTimesheetTableDto, HashMap<String, AbstractField<?>>>();
BeanItemContainer<ReviewTimesheetTableDto> data = new BeanItemContainer<ReviewTimesheetTableDto>(
        ReviewTimesheetTableDto.class);
private Table table;

public void init() {
    // Create a data source and bind it to a table
    table = new Table("", data);
    table.addStyleName("generateColumnTable");
    table.setWidth("100%");
    table.setPageLength(table.getItemIds().size());
    table.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] { "chkBox", "taskDate", "employeeId", "taskId", "crJiraId",
            "taskDesc","hour","minute"/*, "Delete" */});

    table.setColumnHeader("chkBox", "Select");
    table.setColumnHeader("taskDate", "Task Date");
    table.setColumnHeader("employeeId", "Employee ID");
    table.setColumnHeader("taskId", "Task ID");
    table.setColumnHeader("crJiraId", "Subtask ID");
    table.setColumnHeader("taskDesc", "Task Description");
    table.setColumnHeader("hour", "Hour");
    table.setColumnHeader("minute", "Minute");
    
    table.setEditable(true);

    table.setTableFieldFactory(new ImmediateFieldFactory());
}
public class ImmediateFieldFactory extends DefaultFieldFactory {
    
    @Override
    public Field<?> createField(Container container, Object itemId,
            Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
        final ReviewTimesheetTableDto timesheetDetail = (ReviewTimesheetTableDto) itemId;
        
        Map<String, AbstractField<?>> tableRow = null;

        if(tableItem.get(timesheetDetail) == null)
        {
            tableItem.put(timesheetDetail,
                    new HashMap<String, AbstractField<?>>());
            
        }
        tableRow = tableItem.get(timesheetDetail);
        
        if ("taskId".equals(propertyId)) {
            GComboBox box = new GComboBox();
            tableRow.put("taskId", box);
            setTaskValues(box, timesheetDetail);
            //addTaskListener(box);
            box.setData(timesheetDetail);
            if(timesheetDetail != null && timesheetDetail.getTaskId() != null) {
                box.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getTaskId().getValue());
            }
            if(isSubmit){
                box.setReadOnly(true);
            }
            
            if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
                box.setReadOnly(false);
            }
            return box;
        }else if ("crJiraId".equals(propertyId)) {
            TextField field = new TextField();
            field.setEnabled(true);
            field.setWidth("200px");
            field.setNullRepresentation("");
            if(isSubmit){
                field.setReadOnly(true);
            }
            if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
                field.setReadOnly(false);
            }
            field.setMaxLength(50);
            
            field.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getCrJiraId());
            tableRow.put("crJiraId", field);
            return field;
        }else if ("taskDesc".equals(propertyId)) {
            TextField field = new TextField();
            field.setEnabled(true);
            field.setWidth("300px");
            field.setNullRepresentation("");
            field.setReadOnly(false);
            tableRow.put("taskDesc", field);
            field.setMaxLength(2000);
            field.setData(timesheetDetail);
            addDetailPopupForTaskDesc(field, null);
            
            if(timesheetDetail.getTaskDesc() != null){
                field.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getTaskDesc());
            }
            field.setReadOnly(true);
            if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
                field.setReadOnly(false);
            }
            return field;
        }else if ("hour".equals(propertyId)) {
            GComboBox box = new GComboBox();
            box.setWidth("60px");
            tableRow.put("hour", box);
            box.addValueChangeListener(addHourListener(box));
            setHourValues(box, timesheetDetail);
            box.setData(timesheetDetail);
            if(isSubmit){
                box.setReadOnly(true);
            }
            if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
                box.setReadOnly(false);
            }
            return box;
        }else if ("minute".equals(propertyId)) {
            GComboBox box = new GComboBox();
            box.setWidth("80px");
            tableRow.put("minute", box);
            box.addValueChangeListener(addMinuteListener(box));
            setMinuteValues(box, timesheetDetail);
            box.setData(timesheetDetail);
            if(isSubmit){
                box.setReadOnly(true);
            }
            if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
                box.setReadOnly(false);
            }
            return box;
        }else if ("employeeId".equals(propertyId)) {
            /*TextField field = new TextField();
            field.setEnabled(true);
            field.setWidth("100%");
            field.setNullRepresentation("");
            field.setReadOnly(true);
            field.setMaxLength(50);
            field.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getEmpId());
            tableRow.put("empId", field);
            return field;*/
            
            GComboBox box = new GComboBox();
            tableRow.put("employeeId", box);
            setEmpValues(box, timesheetDetail);
            box.setData(timesheetDetail);
            if(timesheetDetail != null && timesheetDetail.getEmployeeId() != null) {
                box.setDescription(timesheetDetail.getEmployeeId().getValue());
            }
            if(isSubmit){
                box.setReadOnly(true);
            }
            if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
                box.setReadOnly(false);
            }
            /*if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
                box.setReadOnly(false);
            }*/
            return box;
        }else if ("taskDate".equals(propertyId)) {
            DateField field = new DateField();
            field.setEnabled(true);
            field.setWidth("110px");
            field.setReadOnly(true);
            if(timesheetDetail.getIsAdd() != null && timesheetDetail.getIsAdd()){
                field.setReadOnly(false);
            }
            field.setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            
            tableRow.put("taskDate", field);
            return field;
        }else if ("chkBox".equals(propertyId)) {
            CheckBox field = new CheckBox();
            field.setEnabled(true);
            field.setWidth("30px");
            field.setDescription(SHAConstants.SELECT);
            
            **field.setValue(true);**
            
            tableRow.put("chkBox", field);
            return field;
        }else {
            Field<?> field = super.createField(container, itemId,
                    propertyId, uiContext);

            if (field instanceof TextField)
                field.setWidth("100%");
            field.setEnabled(true);
            return field;
        }
    }
}
```

Your contribution will be very much helpful. Thanks in advance.
Kindly find Output of above code below. [image: Output of above code below]

Comment: If you are binding a `ReviewTimesheetTableDto` object to each row and the `chkBox` property is bound to the object's field, you should check the values of the `ReviewTimesheetTableDto` objects in the container. If the bound values are false the checkbox is unselected.

Comment: Hi Axel, Thank you very much for your support. It got the desired result.